# viewDidLoad() of segue.destinationViewController called twice before prepareForSegue()

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

So what I'm trying to do is to send an object from a tableViewController to a collectionViewController via the sender parameter of the prepareForSegue method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but for some reason the viewDidLoad method of that collectionViewController is being called twice before prepareForSegue. Here's the relevant code from the tableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let challenge = dataModel.challenges[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowChallengeSegue", sender: challenge)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ...
    else if segue.identifier == "ShowChallengeSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ChallengeViewController
        controller.challenge = sender as! Challenge
    }
}
```

After adding a bunch of print statements the following is happening in sequence:

1. tableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called
2. destinationViewController's (collectionViewController) viewDidLoad is called
3. destinationViewController's (collectionViewController) viewDidLoad is called again
4. tableViewController's prepareForSegue is called

I have no idea why is this happening, would appreciate any help.

**Edit** - I replaced the collectionViewController with a tableViewController and everything seems be working fine so it might be something related specifically to UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 0):

you must have took segue from cell instead of whole controller so that segue is performed twice

Please take segue from Controller then try

OR

add this code

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - the segue is being triggered from the viewController so that the sender parameter is the set "challenge" object and not the cell also. So that's not it I'm afraid.

Comment: IIRC shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier does not get called if one is using performSegueWithIdentifier. Still gave it a shot and it does not help, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@Gerwazy Sokołowski

Check your xib file in storyboard. i think you linked segue from button or any other view. segue should be set with UIViewcontroller then you can call performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: Double-checked - segue is most definitely triggered from the viewController itself and not the cell or any other subview.